# how to trim leading zeros before displaying the field in jsp?

Tags: jsp, trim

I have data coming into JSP from database. this has teh value like 0000000019 (string). I need to display it as 19. leading zeros needs to trimed out.how would you do it in jsp?

**Update**

see I have a session variable as :

```
<c:set var = "tCharge" value="${redata.totalCharge}" />
```

how do you trm all the leading zeros from "tCharge" or ${redata.totalCharge}

Comment: @raj If you have updates to your question, please add them by editing your question as oppose to posting new items below here. All posts below your question should be answers (or comments on answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<fmt:formatNumber value="${redata.totalCharge}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

is the data an integer number? the fastest way is

```
<%=Integer.parseInt("0000000019")%>
```

or if it comes from the session...

```
<%=Integer.parseInt(((YourRedataClass)session.getAttribute("redata")).getTotalCharge())%>
```

Comment: i know, but the data inside the string is an integer number?

Comment: I have the field stored in session variable as ${redata.totalCharge} how to trim this one ?

Comment: Anybody ???   I have the field stored in session variable as ${redata.totalCharge}  how to remove leading zeros

Comment: I edited the anwser. You should take a look how Stackoverflow works before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Always zeros? Converting it to number should do it.

```
<%
  String sNum="0000000019";
  int iNum = Integer.parseInt(sNum);
  sNum = Integer.toString(iNum);
%>
```

Comment: I have the field stored in session variable as ${redata.totalCharge} how to trim this one ?

Answer (score 0):

`fmt:formatNumber` didn't work for me. But `fmt:parseNumber` works:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:parseNumber value="0000000123456" />
```