# how to remove leading zeros from a session variable in jsp

Tags: jsp

i have a session variable `-${reData.totalCharge}` it may have values like  `000000033`. when I display the value in JSP I need only `33` to be displayed. how do you do this ? this is defined as string as the data is stored as charecter in DB2 database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to trim leading zeros before displaying the field in jsp ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786966/how-to-trim-leading-zeros-before-displaying-the-field-in-jsp)

Comment: Consider registering your user account so that you'll be able to login using the same account on every computer/browser and thus be able to access and maintain your profile with all questions. Right now you've at least 3 unregistered accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(value)` would work. But do that in the preprocessing code, rather than in the JSP. Also, `<fmt:formatNumber />` should work.

But ultimately - try fixing this in the database. You shouldn't be storing integers as strings.

Comment: can you please shed some example ?