# String to integer conversion in Java/JSP

Tags: java, string, jsp

I have a variable `cost` defined in a DB2 table as `String`. I'm getting it into a value object where it is defined as a `String` as well. I need to check if the value coming in from DB2 is only spaces. If it is only spaces, I need to move 0 into it. I also need to remove leading zeros from it. I may get `cost` as `0000123`. But in JSP I need to display it as `123`. How do you do that? I'm storing the vo data into a session variable and using this, I'm displaying the data in JSP.

Comment: You've asked this problem [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797034/how-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-a-session-variable-in-jsp) [times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786966/how-to-trim-leading-zeros-before-displaying-the-field-in-jsp) before, with different accounts. Please don't re-ask the same question again. If the answers didn't satisfy you somehow, clarify that by editing/improving the question or posting comments on the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider changing your database schema to store the value in a numeric field. If you can't do that, consider changing the value object to store it as a numeric field and parse the string you retrieve from the database.

Comment: Indeed, fix the problem at its roots (fix the data type in DB), do not hack/workaround it afterwards.

Comment: I did change the value object to store it as integer. just with that change it is working fine. anybody seeing any issue with that ?

Comment: If the database column contains non-number strings, you may still run into problems because they aren't convertible to integers. As said, preferably fix the design problem at its roots. Make the column type an `INTEGER` or maybe `SMALLINT` and no one will ever be able to *insert* non-numeric strings into the column.

Comment: ok thanks. I will make the field as integer in DB2 side. and default to 0.

Comment: Now yet register your account so that the other accounts with all those questions can be merged and you can use one and same account everyplace :)

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that most of what you have described sounds like extremely poor design, you can continue the path and use a scriptlet. The following example uses [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to accomplish your task:

```
<%= org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils.toInt(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.trimToNull(cost),0) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your database. Use `Integer.parseInt` [(javadoc)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). (This is assuming we are dealing with integers here, otherwise use the equivalent in `Double`). Create a function to process your String number and use it in your JSP.

```
<%
function String processNumber(String value){
  if(value == null || value.trim().length() == 0){
     value = "0"//use a zero if all we have is whitespace or if the value is null
  }

  int intValue = 0;//store the integer version (which won't have leading zeros)
  try{
    int intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);//process the number
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    intValue = 0;//use 0 if there's a problem
  }
  return "" + intValue;//return the String version free of leading zeros
}
%>
<p>Number: <%= processNumber(getValue()) //replace getValue with however you get your value %></p>
```